# How to speed up Group by query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a mysql query that take 30 seconds to run. there are more than 3millions rows in the table

here is the db structure :

```
text (VARCHAR(64)), 
kpi1 (INT), 
kpi2 (INT), 
position (DECIMAL),
date(DATE)
device (VARCHAR(32))
```

Here is the query :

```
select date, sum(kpi1), sum(kpi2) FROM  `table_name` GROUP BY date ;
```

Explain method gives me this result :

```
ID  | select type   | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtred | extra
1   | SIMPLE        | table_name   | NULL       | index | UNIQUE,DATE    | DATE | 3       | NULL | 3316480 | 100.00  | NULL
```

I have an index on date.

Here the result with profiling :

```
mysql> show profile for query 1;
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000080 |
| checking permissions |  0.000011 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000021 |
| init                 |  0.000023 |
| System lock          |  0.000011 |
| optimizing           |  0.000007 |
| statistics           |  0.000021 |
| preparing            |  0.000019 |
| Sorting result       |  0.000007 |
| executing            |  0.000005 |
| Sending data         | 32.814836 |
| end                  |  0.000011 |
| query end            |  0.000009 |
| closing tables       |  0.000009 |
| freeing items        |  0.000082 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000013 |
+----------------------+-----------+
16 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The query needs the index `(date, kpi1, kpi2)`

Comment: @NB once grouped, this is not returning a lot of rows. only 345 are returned

Comment: Now, that's useful piece of info and yes, Raymond's suggestion makes more sense. To get more info out of MySQL, you should use profiling to detect if the bottleneck is because of HDD. `SET PROFILING = 1; <your query>; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1` and then check what it says, it shows every step from opening files to writing to the socket. Did you tune your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable at all?

Comment: @NB I updated the question with the result of profiling. the bottleneck seems to be in sending data... What is the good config for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` controls how much memory MySQL uses for storing indexes. You want this as high as possible, ideally the size of your data set. Common practice is to have 90% of available ram dedicated to MySQL. This setting shifts I/O from disk to RAM, which makes MySQL fly. Now, as for the profiler  - there was a bug in certain MySQL versions where the time was actually the time from **previous** step. This means that `executing` part takes up time, which makes sense as it sorts 3.3 million records. Increasing the buffer pool should make that operation much, much faster.

Comment: i set the buffer_size to 1G and devided the time of operation by 2. but that still a huge time and is not a long term solution cause the db's size will increase over time.  right now, the table size is about 211Mo so i think I have enought RAM allocated to handle this... what version of Mysql is correcting this bug ? may be i just have to upgrade ?

Answer (score 1):

If the data on historical dates is static (as in, not changing because the date / activity is already done), then this is a perfect example of when to use a summary table.  Create a separate table that is nothing but the date and the aggregates as you need them.  Do that for all days prior to the current, so only at the end of the day, you insert (such as some daily trigger) the sum of the prior day.  You could even include the count of records, something like

```
insert into MyDailySummaryTable 
   ( Date, kpi1Sum, kpi2Sum, numRecs )
   select date, 
          sum(kpi1) kpi1Sum, 
          sum(kpi2) kpi2Sum,
          count(*) numRecs
      FROM  
         `table_name` 
      where
         date < curdate()
      GROUP BY 
         date ;
```

then for each day after the initial load

```
insert into MyDailySummaryTable 
   ( Date, kpi1Sum, kpi2Sum, numRecs )
   select date, 
          sum(kpi1) kpi1Sum, 
          sum(kpi2) kpi2Sum,
          count(*) numRecs
      FROM  
         `table_name` 
      where
         date = date_add( curdate(), interval -1 day )
      GROUP BY 
         date ;
```

If your "date" field has timestamp information too, you may need to adjust the query to ignore the time portions.

Then, when trying to run your totals, you can just query from the MyDailySummaryTable directly and have instant results.

You could even expand the query aggregate table to include the counts per device in case you ever wanted to find tracking info for that one specific device too.

Comment: thank for your solution, I had it in mind but guess there is something wrong with my query or configuration. if nothing is wrong, i'll apply this solution.